# How to get row value to map with columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Table: `fieldTable` (with only one column `ColumnFileName`)

```
@fieldTable (ColumnFileName varchar(10))

ColumnFileName: (Values are as below).    
        f1
        f2
        f3
        f4,
        f5
```

Table: `ValueTable`  (9 columns as below)

```
@valuetable(id INT, f1 VARCHAR(100), f2 VARCHAR(100), 
            f3 VARCHAR(100), f4 VARCHAR(100), f5 VARCHAR(100),
            f6 VARCHAR(100), f7 VARCHAR(100), comments VARCHAR(100))

 Id   f1     f2   f3,      f4         f5      f6,     f7       comments
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1   Name   Id   Salary   Interest   Offer   value   Salary   ''
```

How to get result as below (to map Table 1 row's value to column value of Table2):

```
f1,Name,
f2,Id
f3,Salary
f4,Interest
f5,Offer,
f6,value,
f7,Salary,
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. Can you post actual ddl for the table and some sample data? Here is great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Do you mean map with column **names** instead of mapping with columns?

Comment: you mean get table1's value with another table's field

Comment: Need only those column values from Table 2 where it exists into Table1. so, f1,f2,f3,f4,f5 are existed as values for table 1 so, need to map these value as column into table 2 and retrieve that result.

Comment: You would need to hardcode names with values. Ugly SQL is your only option.

Comment: Lots of ways, some of them so easy and obvious that I'm suspicious as to why you're asking.  Is there really nothing more to what you need to do?

Comment: I can see cursor to do. not sure if any other option that makes easy.

Comment: Looks to me like you need to unpivot the data in valueTable so you can join the columns to columnfilename.  Unpivot is here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177410(v=sql.105) but is @valuetable dynamic on the columns it could contain?  if sy dynamci SQL is needed.

Comment: Well a super-easy way is to UNION ALL a different query for each row of your desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will get you were you need to be.I first through in some proper inserts so anyone following up could at least have those. Then Basic unpivot and match.

```
DECLARE @FIELDTABLE TABLE (COLUMNFILENAME VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @FIELDTABLE (COLUMNFILENAME)
VALUES ( 'f1')
        ,('f2')
        ,('f3')
        ,('f4')
        ,('f5')
        ,('f6')
        ,('f7')

DECLARE @VALUETABLE TABLE (Id INT,f1 varchar(100),f2 varchar(100),f3 varchar(100),f4 varchar(100),f5 varchar(100),f6 varchar(100),f7 varchar(100),comments varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @VALUETABLE (Id, f1, f2, f3, f4,f5,f6,f7,comments)
        Values (1, 'Name','Id','Salary','Interest','Offer','value','Salary','')

SELECT F.COLUMNFILENAME
        ,v.Columns

FROM @FIELDTABLE f
inner join
(
SELECT Columns, Columns2
FROM (
    SELECT *
        from @VALUETABLE
    ) cp
UNPIVOT
(
    Columns FOR Columns2 in (F1,F2,F3, f4,f5,f6,f7)
) as UP
) v
on f.COLUMNFILENAME = v.Columns2
```